# Overloading the assignment operator vs. providing an implicit constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have just learned on page 563 of **C++ Primer** (5th edition) that one can overload the assignment operator. So, if I am writing a class `C` and it makes sense to assign an integer to an object of this class, then I can provide an assignment operator with an `rhs` of type `int`. Then the clients of my class can write:

```
C c;
...
c = 5;
```

**Question:** Is it true that if such an assignment makes sense, then an implicit constructor `C(int);` should also make sense? If so, then I should really define this constructor instead (which has other uses as well) and never need to overload the assignment operator. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it is normal to have such a constructor, and rare to define any assignment operators other than copy-assignment or move-assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `C` defines a non-`explicit` constructor taking an `int` then you don't necessarily *need* an assignment operator taking an `int`, but it may end up being more efficient.

If `operator=(int)` exists:

```
C c; //default constructor
c = 5; //assignment from int
```

If `C(int)` exists and `operator=(int)` does not:

```
C c; //default constructor
c = 5; //construction of temporary from int, then assignment from C
```

If move semantics are efficient for `C` then the latter may be acceptable. If not, you might want to define that `operator=(int)` anyway. Ultimately, this depends on a number of factors, like how often you are going to be assigning to `C`, how expensive copies are etc. Understand the issues, work out how they apply to your class, then choose the most reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it true that if such an assignment makes sense, then an implicit
>   constructor C(int); should also make sense?

In depends. The difference between the assignment and implicit constructor is that in assignment there is already a set-up object, while in implicit conversion you have to create an object given int only.

In a most common scenario, the assignment operator will just forget all the data of the original object. In such a case you should be also able to convert int to `C`. However, I can imagine situations when the assignment operator actually *uses* some data from the original object. In such a case, no conversion constructor can be thought of.

A simple example: consider numerical simulation project, which has class `Mesh` — set of points in space on which the calculations are done, and class `Field` that is set of values on that points (say, temperatures in that points). A `Field` can not exist without a `Mesh`:

```
class Field {
    const Mesh& mesh;
    std::vector<int> data;
};
```

Here you can not create `Field(int)` constructor, as you do not have a mesh. However, you may think of `Field::operator=(int)` assignment, which will replace all `data` values with a given `int`, keeping `mesh` intact.

So, the answer to the first your question is: **no**, even is assignment makes sense, the conversion does not always make sense.

However, if that's not your case and both conversion and assignment makes sense, than refer to @TartanLlama's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the assignment operator too, just the constructor from an `int`

1. C c(5); Calls the constructor taking an `int` as an argument.
2. C c = 5; Calls the **constructor** taking an `int` as an argument.
3. C c; c = 5; Calls the default constructor, the second statement will call the constructor to an `int`, then the assignment operator.

(2) can cause confusion. The constructor must be used since the object does not exist.